# How to guarantee commutativity in method calls?

Tags: java, oop

I'm playing with the idea of programming without exceptions, using a combination of [Ward Cunningham's Exceptional Value and Meaningless Behavior patterns](http://www.c2.com/ppr/checks.html).

Suppose I have an interface Fraction, meant to represent any quantity that can be represented by dividing 2 other quantities, with a set of operations:

```
interface Fraction {
    
    Fraction add(Fraction f);
    Fraction subtract(Fraction f);
    Fraction multiply(Fraction f);
    Fraction divide(Fraction f);
    
}
```

Now, this interface will have 2 main implementations: a) SimpleFraction, where the denominator is not 0; and b) UndefinedFraction, where the denominator is 0. Both will be created by a factory:

```
public final class SimpleFraction implements Fraction {

    private final int numerator, denominator;

    private SimpleFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
    
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
        
    }
    
    // interface method implementations
    
}

public final class UndefinedFraction implements Fraction {

    private final int numerator;
    
    private UndefinedFraction(int numerator) {
        
        this.numerator = numerator;
        
    }

    // interface method implementations
    
}
```

UndefinedFraction will be an Exceptional Value with Meaningless Behavior: each one of its operations should return an UndefinedFraction. More importantly, if it's used as the argument in the operation of any other fraction, the result should be an UndefinedFraction as well:

```
FractionFactory factory = new FractionFactory();
Fraction simple = factory.fromNumeratorAndDenominator(420, 10);
Fraction undefined = factory.fromNumeratorAndDenominator(42, 0);

assertEquals(simple.add(undefined), undefined);
assertEquals(undefined.add(simple), undefined);
assertEquals(undefined.add(undefined), undefined);
```

How can I enforce this kind of commutativity in the operations involving the UndefinedFraction? I'm looking for options based on polymorphism (for example, they shouldn't rely on boolean checks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is associativity.

Terminology: Given 'a / b', we call a the LHS (Left hand side), and b the RHS, and '/' the operator, and 'divide' the operation. LHS and RHS are both 'operands'.

The problem: Let's say we create 2 flavours of undefined. We have 'red undefined' and 'green undefined', and we stick with the same definitions: any operation where the LHS and/or the RHS is 'red undefined' should produce 'red undefined'.

The same rule is applied to 'green undefined': Any operation where LHS and/or RHS is 'green undefined' should be 'green undefined' regardless of the value of the other operand and regardless of the operation.

Unfortunately, that definition is **ambiguous**:

```
Fraction red = factory.newRedUndefined();
Fraction green = factory.newGreenUndefined();
Fraction whatColorIsThis = red.add(green);
```

should that be red, or green? Who gets priority?

This issue should highlight that there is no simple/obvious answer to your question!

Going back to 'a / b' - what you've done (and this is hard to avoid in object oriented languages) is that you're defining the operations available **on the operands**. It's 'a' that has the 'divide' method. It's not that the concept 'divide' is an object and it has a method that takes 2 arguments. In other words, you have this:

```
a.divide(b);
```

and not this:

```
fractionMathSystem.divide(a, b);
```

Basic designs that make `a.divide(b)` work inherently associate 'left' (as in, 'a' determines the implementation of divide, b is just along for the right), and do not associate 'right', because that's how java is defined.

The problem is, you don't want left associativity here: If 'b' is undefined and 'a' is not, you want 'b' to "override" and take control of the operation.

But you can't do that, and there are no easy language proposals with no caveats to make that happen, because of the red/green undefined problem stated earlier.

The underlying issue is that you've defined an operation (Fraction's divide) that should be defined in terms of the operation itself, and not in terms of either operand. Hence, `fractionNumberSystem.divide(a, b)` makes much more sense; you can write the code of 'if either operand is undefined, the result is undefined' there, or even introduce a system whereby each operand is asked if it wants to take charge of the operation, and offer each operand a hierarchy of priority, where the number system will pick operand that reports it has the highest priority, and ask it to do the operation.

Fortunately, you can make `a.divide(b)` boil down to that:

```
public class Fraction {
    public void divide(Fraction rhs) {
        return numberSystem.divide(this, rhs);
    }
}
```

And now numberSystem.divide can do whatever you want it to do. The concept of 'the divide operation associates to undefined first, whichever side undefined is on' can then be programemd in numberSystem's divide method. Or, you can make it more 'pluggable', find a way to solve the problem of red/green (when both sides want to take control of the operation, how do you decide which one "wins"? is red.add(green) red or green?), however you want. Perhaps by checking if the Fraction involved is an instance of "OperationControllingFraction" (a subtype you'd make), and having the OperationControllingFraction type have `radd` methods (right-associative-add), as well as an `int priority()` method.

NB: A tip: `add` is a bad name. `plus` works better. `a.add(b)` suggests that this modifies `a`. `a.plus(b)` suggests a remains unchanged, and that a new value is returned. Yes, `BigInteger` and friends are badly named. It happens; those APIs are pretty old, I don't think it's a good idea to perpetuate obvious design mistakes in an attempt to be consistent, given that the design mistake is grave enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed explanation, @rzwitserloot! It's kinda bittersweet,  because although it provides a solution for my problem, it apparently makes it impossible to achieve the benefits that I was pursuing: clean error handling while respecting encapsulation and keeping my codebase succint. I coded an example using the methodology you suggest, and it wasn't satisfying at all. I guess I'm going back to plain old exception handling, or monadic structures... Both of which I dislike, although for different reasons.